# NodeJS Website very slow on production server

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, apache2, server

First of all, i'm sorry for my bad english.

I have a strange problem, i bought a dedicated server on "OVH". 
I install
- Debian 7 stable
- node and npm
- apache2

I put a node application ( on the port "9000" ) and a basic html page at the root :
-var/www/
--------index.html
--------nodeApp/

So, let's say my server have this adresse : 1.12.123.123

When i trie to access to my server at home on :
 - "1.12.123.123" : i get index.html really fast.
 - "1.12.123.123:9000" : i get my node app really fast.

BUT, when i trie to access to my server at work on :
 - "1.12.123.123" : i get index.html really fast.
 - "1.12.123.123:9000" : i can't  access to the page of my node app.

Do you have an idea of what is going on ?

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issues.

I use virtualhost now, so i have only the port 80 open on my server.
And everything work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall setting. Port 9000 might be blocked by your firewall.